# HDIV Refresh Displays Error

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, spring-security, hdiv

I am using Spring3 security, Spring3 mvc with jquery and HDIV 2.1.2.

When I run the application and press any menu or open any page in console I got the following exception, but in the browser application is working fine.

Exception is.......

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.hdiv.exception.HDIVException: IDataComposer has not been initialized in request.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the request hasn't been processed by HDIV's filter. Could you verify that HDIV's filter is configured properly and the request is processed by it?